# How disable Java in Chrome 23?

Tags: java, chrome, zero-day

Well in case someone doesn't know yet... there is a new Java zero day.

I'm trying to disable it on Chrome but I can't find any option. Google searches says that the option for deactivate it is on chrome://plugins however I don't see such option there.

Comment: It may have an unexpected name in your `chrome://plugins` tab. On my system (Kubuntu 12.10) the relevant plugin is called IcedTea, with a small note in the description that it's responsible for java applets.

Comment: Incidentally it's not a new 0-day, technically it's not even a 0-day as Oracle knew about it in August.... So lets be correct, it's a regularly exploited unpatched vulnerability.

Comment: I know you said 23, but 26 lets me disable any plugin. Maybe you could move to 26?

Answer (score 2):

If you can't disable java from `chrome://plugins`, you can use the `-disable-java` startup switch. Example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -disable-java
```

Navigating to http://java.com/en/download/help/testvm.xml after a restart of the browser should give the message:

> No working Java was detected on your system. Install Java by clicking
>   the button below.

You can read about other switches in [The Power User’s Guide to Google Chrome](http://lifehacker.com/#!5045904/the-power-users-guide-to-google-chrome).

To improve security for the future, not just react to public exploits, you might also want to go to `chrome://chrome/settings/content` and check `Click to play` on the Plug-ins:

[image]

This will wait for your click in order to run the plug-in therefore limiting your exposure.

And this should protect you from more than just Java vulnerabilities:

- Secunia [PSI](http://secunia.com/vulnerability_scanning/personal/)/[VIM](http://secunia.com/products/corporate/vim) for notification of updates, vulnerabilities and automatic updates
- Microsoft [EMET](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1677) for preventing stack overflows and similar
- [BufferZone](http://www.trustware.com/) for protection from drive-by installers
- [iCore Virtual Accounts](http://icoresoftware.com/) for times when you need to walk the dark side of the net on a production machine